# Vue input event not capturing entire field

Tags: vue.js, binding, vue-component, v-model

I have a vue component that adds a search bar and search bar functionality.  It contains this line:

```html
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Address" v-model="searchQuery" v-on:input="(event) => this.$emit('queryChange', event)">
```

This captures the text in the search bar and emits it.

In my vue, this triggers my updateSearchQuery function:
`this.searchQuery = event.data` which merely saves the users input in the `searchQuery` property in my vue.  Everything works fine when I do this, until, I make a search and then, make another call using the same `this.searchQuery` data.

For example, I'm trying to filter results with the search query '956'.  I enter it and this call is made: `GET /users?cp=1&pp=20&se=956`, just like it should. Then after the page loads, if I go to page 2 of the results, this is the call that is made to the server: `GET /users?cp=2&pp=20&se=6`.  Instead of saving 956 as the queryStr in the the view, **it only saves the most recent character entered, instead of the entire content of the serch text**.

This happens every time I type in multiple characters as a search query, and then make another call to the server using the unchanged `this.searchQuery` variable.  If my initial search query is only a single character, it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I emit the entirety of the text in the search bar, after any change, so that I can always save the whole search query, instead of the just the most recent change?

**EDIT: I've add some more code below so the data flow is easier to follow:**

Here is the template and script for the search component:

```
<template>
  <div class="level-item">
    <div class="field has-addons">
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Address" v-model.lazy="searchQuery" v-on:input="(event) => this.$emit('queryChange', event)">
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <div class="button is-light" @click="clearInput">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:#ffaaaa"></i>
                    </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <button class="button is-info" @click="onSearch(searchQuery)">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Search',
    props: {onSearch: Function},
    data () {
      return {
        searchQuery: ''
      }
    },
    watch: {},
    methods: {
      clearInput () {
        this.searchQuery = ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

the emitted queryChange event is caught and listened to in the vue page:
`<Search :onSearch="onSearch" v-on:queryChange="updateSearchQuery">` and this triggers the updateSearchQuery function:

```
updateSearchQuery (event) {
        this.searchQuery = event.data
        console.log(event.data + '  ||  event.data')
        console.log(this.searchQuery + '  ||  this.searchQuery')
      }
```

Theoretically, the searchQuery data in my vue should be a copy of the searchQuery   data in my component, which is itself merely a copy of whatever the user has input in the search bar.

Then when I make a call to the server I'm using the value in this.searchQuery in my vue:

```
onSearch (search) {
   this.makeServerQuery(1, search)
},
onPaginate (page) {
   this.makeServerQuery(page, this.searchQuery)
},
makeServerQuery (page = null, search = null) {
   let queryStr = ''
   if (page !== null) {
       queryStr += '?cp=' + page + '&pp=' + this.perPage
   }
   if (this.searchQuery !== '') {
       queryStr += '&se=' + this.searchQuery
   }   .....
```

The on `onSearch(search)` function is called whenever the search button is pressed.  That seems to work fine, because when the button is pressed the entire searchQuery is passed, not just the last change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input event's `data` value appears to be the last typed character, and not the current value of the input. A simple fix is:

`@input="$emit('queryChange', searchQuery)"`

This works because the model will always be updated before the input event handler runs.

Here's a complete working component example:

```html
<input
  v-model="searchQuery"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Address"
  @input="onInput"
/>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return { searchQuery: '' };
  },
  methods: {
    onInput() {
      console.log(this.searchQuery);
      this.$emit('queryChange', this.searchQuery);
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Making those changes causes all the data being emitted to equal `undefined`.

Comment: It should cause the emitted value to be a string instead of an object. Your `updateSearchQuery` will need be something like `this.searchQuery = event` instead of `this.searchQuery = event.data` (I'd recommend renaming those variables).

Comment: I will definitely change the name, just trying to get it working before I do that.

I changed the event.data back to just event, to capture a string, but nothing is being sent, and I am using the `@input` syntax you suggested above. `console.log(event + '  ||  event')` and `console.log(this.searchQuery + '  ||  this.searchQuery')` both return nothing.

Comment: I'd like you to debug this by logging in the component itself and not in the parent. Please make your component look like the updated code in the example. Now does it log the correct value?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  When I have the .lazy on the v-model it didn't work, but after your changes it does.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! You're correct - `.lazy` would prevent this from working.